# Get field by value

Tags: java

There is a interface, that define codes for keyboard. Every button have code.

```
public interface KeyMap{

private static final int A = 23;
private static final int B = 24;
//other keys
...
}
```

But my question is: how to get letter (A,B,...) by number (23,24,...).
Something like:

```
public String getKey(int value);
```

I tried resolve creating Map, but then there is need to initialize full Map again and again. i thought about Java reflect but cant find right method to do it.

Comment: you are implementing your own collection like `Map` :)

Comment: use a `HashMap` (or any `Map` implementation) and put values like   `map.put("A", 23)`. To get value `map.get("A")`, returns `23`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java Reflection would be possible, but it would be pretty slow, since you have to iterate through all fields to get the one with the correct value.

Another suggestion:

```
enum KeyCode {

  A(23),
  ...;

  private int code;

  private static final Map<Integer, KeyCode> keys = new HashMap<Integer, KeyCode>();

  static {
    for(KeyCode code : values()) {
        keys.put(code.code, code);
    }
  }

  private KeyCode(int code) {
    this.code = code;
  }

  public static KeyCode getKey(int code) {
   return keys.get(code);
  }

}
```

This allows you to simple do...

```
KeyCode code = KeyCode.getCode(23);
String name = code.name(); // assuming not null here, should be "A"
```

This would be pretty fast, etc. But of course, another question would be, if you cannot use an existing framework. As far as I know, Swing already does some key mapping, for example.

**Edit:**

Ok, as you seem to have to use a pre-defined [class](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/ShortcutAction.KeyCode.html), reflection actually seems the only way to go... This method will allow you to get a map of all field names by value.

```
public static Map<Object, String> getFieldsByValue(Class<?> clz) {
    Map<Object, String> map = new HashMap<Object, String>();
    // Remember: Class.getField() returns only PUBLIC fields
    for (Field field : clz.getFields()) {
        // Check if it's a static variable
        if (Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) {
            // Add other checks, for example for "integer", if you want.
            try {
                // field.get(null) returns the value of the field for a static field
                map.put(field.get(null), field.getName());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // should not happen, as we made sure the field is static
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // should not happen, as we only listed public fields
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

You can call this method once in a static initializer block (see example above) to create the Map once and then access it, which makes the runtime better:

```
static {
    keyMap = getFieldsByValue(com.vaadin.event.ShortcutAction.KeyCode.class);

    // example
    String name = keyMap.get(23); // should be "A"
}
```

Comment: It is actuallly [vaadin's keyMap](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/event/ShortcutAction.KeyCode.html), that is used for Shortcuts, but want also make a "Help Window" with all shortcuts on page, so i look for way to get names of keys.

Comment: Ok, in this case, reflection is pretty much your only choice. Will update the answer.